# Where to find GNU Make 4.3 for Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, make

I find myself with a use for GNU Make's grouped target feature which made its appearance in 4.3. I am only running Ubuntu 20.04 though, so I still have 4.2.1. Is it possible to find that version of make without upgrading to 21.04?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply download newer deb-package from [21.10 repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/impish/make) and install it by using commands below:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/m/make-dfsg/make_4.3-4ubuntu1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install ./make_4.3-4ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

Comment: Does Ubuntu have something like Debian's backports? If so, that would do something like what you're describing, but updating it would be easier.

Comment: @cocomac, see https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal-backports/allpackages .

Comment: Thanks. That's kind of what I hoped for. I had a small issue when referencing the deb file via relative name. Using the absolute path worked.

Comment: That wget location is now dead.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to install it on any modern system [using the source files](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/make/):

1. Open Terminal (if it’s not already open)
2. Download the version you want from the GNU site:

   ```
   wget https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/make/make-4.3.tar.gz
   ```
3. Extract and build:

   ```
   tar xfz make-4.3.tar.gz
   cd make-4.3
   ./configure
   make
   ```

Comment: Thanks. I know building from source is always an option, but for something like this I'd prefer to a) install in the canonical location, and b) not install in the canonical location in such a way that the system's dependency handling machinery is blind to what I've installed.